# What is the right order in creating Kafka Producer and calling the methods send(), flush() and close()?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have the below mentioned different models where I create Kafka producer and call different methods, but not sure what is the right approach to program it so that flow should not break and performance should not be affected. Kindly help.

Model 1:

```
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName, 
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
    producer.close();
}
```

Model 2:

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++) {

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName, 
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
    producer.close();
}
```

Model 3:

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName, 
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
}
producer.close();
```

Model 4:

```
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName,
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
}
```

Model 5:

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName, 
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
}
```

Model 6:

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
        topicName, 
        String.valueOf(i)
    );

    producer.send(data);
    producer.flush();
}
producer.close();
```

Comment: *so that flow should not break and performance should not be affected* Neither are we. You'll have to try them to find the one that best meets your evaluation criteria.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Tried all models which I showcased here, few models run normally and rest of the models returned IllegalStateException, so question arise in my brain to get this doubt clarified. Also I'm not sure if any performance effects will be there for the models which are running smoothly, as I'm only handling limited amount of data available.

Answer (score 2):

The Model 3 seems should be correct with following change

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
    try {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, String.valueOf(i));
            producer.send(data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        producer.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the example below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));

producer.close();
```

as u known, The send() method is asynchronous. When called it adds the record to a buffer of pending record sends and immediately returns. This allows the producer to batch together individual records for efficiency.

And we can set the buffer.memory or batch.size to flush automatically